# Void function usage issue, I'm new to C

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, function-definition

the task is to print ascending order numbers using only void function. Any insight on what's wrong with the code? Explanation too would be appreciated

```
#include<stdio.h>
void listNumbersAsc(int start, int end);
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    printf("Enter the range of numbers maintaining start at first and end at second:");
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    
   listNumbersAsc(x, y);
}
void listNumbersAsc(int start, int end){
    
    int i,s,e;
    
    if(start>=end){
        s=start;
        e=end;
    }
    else{
        s=end;
        e=start;
    }
    
    for(i=s; i<=e; i++){
        printf("%d",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. First you should tell us what is wrong with your program. What is your input, your output and your expected output?

Comment: Your logic seems backwards. Should be `if(start > end) { s=end; e=start; }`

Comment: You should generally check the return value of `scanf` and other IO functions. Also, output to `stdout` is typically line buffered and may not show up until you either `fflush(stdout)` or print a `\n`. In this case that should not be an issue as it is flushed on program termination.

Comment: It's worth getting into the habit of checking the return value from `scanf` function family from the outset. It might seem like extra work, but will pay off in time saved later. Quite often, it's that value which we use to drive the program logic flow.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void listNumbersAsc(int start, int end);
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    printf("Enter the range of numbers maintaining start at first and end at second:");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);

   listNumbersAsc(x, y);
}
void listNumbersAsc(int start, int end){
    
    int i,s,e;
    
    if(start<=end){
        s=start;
        e=end;
    }
    else{
        s=end;
        e=start;
    }

    for(i=s; i<=e; i++){
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
}
```

You `if` statement in `listNumbersAsc` function wasn't correct.

Also added a space between two `%d` in `scanf("%d %d",&x,&y)` to separate two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of the function is that this for loop

```
for(i=s; i<=e; i++){
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

can be executed inly once if initially start is specified equal to end due to this if statement

```
if(start>=end){
    s=start;
    e=end;
}
else{
    s=end;
    e=start;
}
```

That is due to this if statement start can not be less than end.

Also there are redundant variables in the function

The function can be defined the following way

```
void listNumbersAsc( int start, int end )
{
    if ( end < start )
    {
        int tmp = start;
        start = end;
        end = tmp;
    }

    do
    {    
        printf( "%d ", start );
    } while ( start++ != end );
    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Pay attention to that this loop

```
for(i=s; i<=e; i++){
```

shown in your question and in the other answer is in general wrong. If the user will specify the value `INT_MAX` for the parameter end then the loop can be infinite.

Comment: Ah A different approach I see. Thanks for the help!